# Javascript Regex with variables in a loop with escaping characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

**What I want**

I want to loop through an array of strings, and replace each instance of [!0!] with the string it belongs to. This requires passing a variable inside a loop to the regex.

**What I've tried**

*All attempts present and commented. Obviously I've tested these individually and not all at once.*

```
var re = '';
for (templ_i=0; templ_i<number_of_fields; templ_i++)
{
    // gives me /[!3!]/, thus doesn't work because the brackets need to be escaped
    re = '/\[!' + templ_i+ '!\]/';
    // escaping the backslashes to preserve them also doesn't work
    // gives me the same as above
    re = new RegExp('/\[!' + templ_i+ '!\]/');
    // gives me /\[!3!\]/
    re = '/\\[!' + templ_i+ '!\\]/';
    // Double escape backslash. Unsurprisingly also doesn't work
    re = '/\\\[!' + templ_i+ '!\\\]/';
    // Works, but of course only for line 3
    re = '/\[!3!\]/';
    // Only works with third re
    svg_template = svg_template.replace(re, d[templ_i]['text']);
    // Works, but of course only for line 3
    svg_template = svg_template.replace(/\[!3!\]/, d[templ_i]['text']);
}
```

**What I get**

I get no matches except where I have a comment `// Works`, and of course isn't working with variables in a loop, but just as declared.

**My theory**

Perhaps it is the backslash being removed when I don't escape it and interpreting the [] as functional, and ignored and interpreted literally when I do escape it. If this is the case, I don't know how to avoid this behavior. I have done hours of research, and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe `re = new Regex('\[!' + templ_i+ '!\]')` would help

Comment: I've tried that as well, will update question.

Comment: Are you sure that the 3rd option isn't working? It seems fine to me.

Comment: If you pass in a string to replace, it will treat it as a string, if you pass in a RegExp object, it will use that pattern to match

So the reason most of those don't work is because he has the forward slash in the string matches, which you do not want, because it will try to match on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try doing:

```
re = new RegExp('\\\[!'+templ_i+'!\\\]', 'g')
```

That will let you match the exact string [!3!].  You definitely need the triple back slash within the string though so that the match picks up the literal [ string to match on.

When you use a string to build a Regex Pattern or in replace, you never include the forward slash by the way, that's ONLY used when you're using a regex literal object.  So you've been trying to match on /[!3!]/  instead of [!3!] in many of those.

Comment: I did try using new RegExp, but not new RegExp with triple back slash. It's always the one thing you didn't think to try. This seems to work. If it checks out, I'll gladly mark this as correct.

Comment: The reason the one slash doesn't work is because the RegExp builds the pattern from the string.  And when you use a single backslash, all that's saying is use the literal character [  but you need both the literal characters \ and [  in your string to generate the correct pattern.

Comment: I think it should be `new RegExp('\\\[!'+templ_i+'!\\\]', 'g')` (note 'g' parameter), to replace all '[!0!]', '[!1!]' etc. in the source string at once.

Comment: It depends on if there are multiple matches in each string, but yes if you have multiple occurrences in your string you should definitely include the g flag

Comment: @Goose mentioned in the comment to my answer below that there may be 'hundreds of [!0!]'.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this situation is finding all pattern places and replace them, instead of iterating over possible data. It looks like this:

```
var svg_template = "some [!0!] text [!1!] with patterns [!foo!]";
var data = {0: {text: "a"}, 1: {text: "b"}, foo: {text: "c"}};
var result = svg_template.replace(/\[!(\w+)!\]/g, function (match, id) {
   return data[id].text;
});
console.log(result);
//> "some a text b with patterns c"
```

Comment: What if I have hundreds of [!0!] to replace?

Comment: Then yes, I'd chose @WakeskaterX's answer but with fixed Regexp. :)